# Media Storage: what is it, and why is it using all my data?

Tags: system, data-monitoring

I am only 5 days into my Billing cycle, and noticed that already like 1/3rd of my data has been used (thanks to My Data Manager)... So I looked to see what has used all this data, and it says it is "Media Storage" that has used up most of my data (it's used up over 35 MB!). This is a system process if i'm not mistaken, so my question is: is this in fact a system process? And why would it be using up so much of my data? What exactly does this process do? Would it be safe to deny it network access?

Comment: Streaming any music or video? In the Google Music beta? Using the Amazon cloud player?

Comment: Nope. No Amazon, no google, no Pandora, and maybe 1 or 2 small youtubes a year... Nothing recently at any rate.

Answer (score 2):

My phone was also using too much data for this process, and the solution for it was to *restrict background data*. You can find this option in *Settings* -> *Data usage* -> *Menu*. Just tick the checkbox.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's a system process. Other apps may use Media Storage to download, play, and stream audio/video. I don't know specifically which media apps actually uses them though. You might try to block it, and see if any functionalities in the media player you regularly uses stops working.

Comment: Hmmm... Well, I don't actually use my phone for media playing. once in a blue moon, a YouTube, but almost never. Would there be anyway to find what is utilizing its services?

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue and i managed to resolve it. here's how:

1. Download the app "GlassWire" from Google play.
2. Go to the options button in the top-left corner and select "Usage".
3. Select "Downloads, Media Storage...".
4. Once it is open, select the settings icon next to "permissions" and clear data.
5. Do this for both "Downloads" and "Media Storage".

This fixed the data consumption made by Media Storage which happens as a result of uploads rather than downloads, and i have no idea what was uploading.

Unfortunately, you will have to do this every time the device is restarted.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score -3):

google photos Picasa may be syncing.